# How Parametered Routing system works in Electric Clojure

Tags: routes, clojure, electric-clojure

I need a little help with how the parameterized routing system works in Electric Clojure.

I tried to create an example as basic as I could to show you what I needed. When I route my user to a new page sometimes I need to carry some information with that routing, I.e. name surname, etc.

Example:

1. page ---->

```
(e/defn first-page []
        (e/client

          (dom/text (str (def sum (+ 2 7))
                         )
                    )
          ;expected result is: "9"


          (router/link [`app.poms-01-20230828/second-page] (dom/text "second page"))

          )
        )
```

When user clicks to second page link ---->

```
(e/defn second-page []
        (e/client

          (dom/text ("the result is:" sum)
                    )
          ;expected result is:  "the result is: 9"
          )
        )
```